# Applying transfer learning to a target model with extra inputs

Tags: lstm, transfer-learning

I am planning to transfer weights from my source model to the target model via transfer learning but I am curious if my case is applicable. Both models will use LSTM to predict water levels.

The left-hand side of the figure shows the source model. This model is surrogate model of a flood model with three inputs X1, X2, and X3, and one output YS (water levels from the flood model).

Right one is showing the target model. Here we have same three inputs from the source model, plus two new inputs that I am planning to add, X4 and X5. Additionally, the output will also differ. It is still water levels but from a different resource.

My aim is to transfer weights from the source model to train the target model. The amount of each input and output are same for the both models, however, X4 and X5 will be introduced as new inputs.

Is this applicable in terms of transfer learning?

[image]